# Can't resolve a promise on exported async function NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bluebird

So I am facing this problem when I exported an async function :

```
async function getItemData(callback) {
    let result = await pool.getConnection(async function(err, con) {
        if (err) throw err;

        let queryPromise = await new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

            con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function(err, rows) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Found records : ' + rows.length);
                    resolve(rows);
                }

            });

        });
    }); 
}

module.exports.getItemData = getItemData;
```

Here is where it is called :

```
app.listen(port, function () {

    console.log('Api server is listening on port '+ port);

    // Call the async function  
    (async () => {  

    let result = await driver.getItemData();

    console.log(result);
    )();

});
```

The console.log inside the promise works. But the console.log outside the function returns undefined.
Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- Your function is not returning anything, so why should `result` be defined?
- I suspect that `getConnection()` is not an async function. You are passing an async function as a callback, but that does not make the function itself async. Therefore, your `await` does nothing.

You could try wrapping your whole function in a `Promise` and return that like so:

```
async function getItemData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Found records : ' + rows.length);
                    resolve(rows);
                }

            });
        });
    }); 
}

module.exports.getItemData = getItemData;
```

Also in your other file, I would just make the whole function async, then you don't need that ugly wrapper:

```
app.listen(port, async () => {

    console.log('Api server is listening on port '+ port);

    let result = await driver.getItemData();

    console.log(result);

});
```